# Show that the line with parametric equations don't intersect

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Show that the line with parametric equations $x = 6 + 8t$, $y = −5 + t$, $z = 2 + 3t$ does not intersect the plane with equation $2x − y − 5z − 2 = 0$.

To answer this do i just plug in the $x$, $y$, and $z$ equation into $2x − y − 5z − 2 = 0$? So $2(6 + 8t) − y − 5(−5 + t) − 2(2 + 3t) = 0 $

Comment: Yes, except your substitution is incorrect; you should get
$$2(6+8t)-(-5+t)-5(2+3t)-2=0.$$

Comment: I get the solution 0t=5. Does that mean there is no intersection?

Comment: Yes; there's no value of $t$ that makes it true.

Answer (score 0):

$2(6+8t)−(−5+t)−5(2+3t)−2=0$

$0t=5$

Therefore, there is no intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution (of the parametric equations into the equation of the plane)  yields $0=5$, which means the intersection is $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

The direction vector of the line $(8,1,3)$ is orthogonal to the normal to the plane $(2,-1,-5)$, as their dot product is zero. Hence the line is parallel to the plane.

As the known point on the line $(6,-5,2)$ does not fulfill the equation of the plane, the line is external to the plane and there is no intersection.

This is the long way to say that

$$2(6+8t)−(−5+t)−5(2+3t)−2=0$$ has no solution.